# Access QNap Web Dav via Map Network Drive

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, ssl, webdav, qnap

When trying to connect to my WebDav server I get "The mapped network drive could not be created because the following error has occurred: Mutual Authentication failed. The Server's password is out of date at the domain controller.".

I am logging in with the correct username and password via SSL.
I'm using xx.xxx.xxx.xxx@SSL@8081\DabWWWRoot\Documents as in my Shared Folders section of QNAP, I have Documents read/write via WebDav.

On my router I have port forward 8081 for the internal IP of the NAS.

Could anyone suggest what is going wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need an ssl certificate to be able to map a webdav drive.
You can easily get a 'Let's Encrypt' certificate for free. In your qnap control panel, go to security and check the 'certificate' tab.